# Trying to convert datetime format in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

This is the date time data I've obtain from a JSON file:

> 220215010100

I wish to convert it into a date time format using SQL. The date time data provided is based on this format:

> YYMMDDHHRRSS

Is there a way to convert it into a datetime format recognized by SQL? For example:

> 2022-02-15 01:01:00

Comment: Are you aware of PostgreSQL [formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)?

Comment: Abra, I tried using this query `to_date('220215010100','YYMMDDHH24MISS') as "Start Date Time"`  But it only output the date and year, the time wasn't shown

Comment: oh... its okay.. I've figured it out.. its using to_timestamp instead. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

```
to_timestamp('220215010100','YYMMDDHHMISS') as "Date Time"
```

to convert it into the date time format requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```sql
     declare @string nvarchar(12)='220215010100' 
     declare @stringfomated nvarchar(15)=( select '20'+SUBSTRING(@string,1,2) +'/'+
     SUBSTRING(@string,3,2) +'/'+
     SUBSTRING(@string,5,2) +' '+
     SUBSTRING(@string,7,2) +':'+
     SUBSTRING(@string,9,2) +':'+
     SUBSTRING(@string,11,2) )
     select CONVERT(datetime,@stringfomated)
```

Comment: No it will not. Philip is using PostgreSQL, not Microsoft SQL Server.